# How to check if OleInitialize has already been called?

Tags: delphi, com, delphi-7

I want to write a Delphi function to register a dll. I want the function to check if OleInitialize has already been called before it does so. I guess I'm trying to avoid the consequences of initializing twice because I'm not sure what they might be. I'm worried that my function won't handle as wide a variety of dlls as regsvr32.exe.

Comment: If your function requires that COM be initialized, and you're not sure whether it will already be initialized, then document your function to state that one of its preconditions is that the application must have already initialized it. Then your function doesn't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690134%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> **Return Value**
>   [...]
>   `S_FALSE` - The COM library is already initialized on this apartment.

... and also:

> Typically, the COM library is initialized on an apartment only once. Subsequent calls will succeed, as long as they do not attempt to change the concurrency model of the apartment, but will return `S_FALSE`.